# How can I continue lines of a script block in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell function to create an OrganizationalUnit. I'm a PS newbie but I've pieced together:

```
function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
  $sb = [scriptblock]::Create(
      "New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path `"$path`"
        -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0"
    )

  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential `
    -ScriptBlock $sb
}
```

But when I invoke this later in the script, I get a message that `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` is an unknown cmdlet.  If I make the command one line

```
"New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path `"$path`" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0"
```

it works.

As I see it, at the end of

```
      "New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path `"$path`"
```

there is an open parenthesis and an open quote so PS should be looking for more input.  Ending that line with a back tick didn't help.  Nor did converting the argument to `Create()` to the form `@" ... "@`.  (This is different from [Why I am getting PowerShell Parsing Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014514) in that I don't have any back ticks, certainly none with spaces after them.)

If I'm making an newbie error here and there's a better way to pass the function parameters to `Invoke-Command`, I'm open to rewriting but failing that, how can break the string passed to `Create()` onto multiple lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I am getting PowerShell Parsing Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014514/why-i-am-getting-powershell-parsing-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* how-to escape inner `"` double quotes, and you *know* how-to spread a command on multiple lines using a *Grave Accent* as an escape character:

```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential `
    -ScriptBlock $sb
```

then you **know** how-to do the last in a script block as well: just double the *Grave Accent* character:

```
  $sb = [scriptblock]::Create(
      "New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path `"$path`" ``
        -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0"
    )
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it makes consistent use of back ticks to escape things which will be evaluated again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> **Chris Nelson:** Your "if you really want to" makes it sound like I'm doing something
>   grossly anti-idomatic to PS. I'm perfectly willing to believe that so
>   I wonder how you'd write it.

Thing is, backticks are frowned upon in [Posh community](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle):

- [READ-02 Avoid backticks](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style%20Guide/Readability.md#read-02-avoid-backticks)

> In general, the community feels you should avoid using those backticks
>   as "line continuation characters" when possible. They're hard to read,
>   easy to miss, and easy to mistype. Also, if you add an extra
>   whitespace after the backtick in the above example, then the command
>   won't work. The resulting error is hard to correlate to the actual
>   problem, making debugging the issue harder.

- [Maximum Line Length](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style%20Guide/Code%20Layout%20and%20Formatting.md#maximum-line-length)

> The preferred way to avoid long lines is to use splatting (see
>   About_Splatting) and PowerShell's implied line continuation inside
>   parentheses, brackets, and braces -- these should always be used in
>   preference to the backtick for line continuation when applicable, even
>   for strings

Since you've asked, how I'd write it, here is some examples:

#### "Structured"

```
function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
    $Template = 'New-ADOrganizationalUnit {0} -Path "{1}" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0'
    $ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create(($Template -f $cn, $path))

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
}
```

#### "Splatted"

```
function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
    $Template = 'New-ADOrganizationalUnit {0} -Path "{1}" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0'
    $ScriptBlock = $Template -f $cn, $path

    $Splat = @{
        ComputerName = $server
        Credential = $Credential
        ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($ScriptBlock)
    }

    Invoke-Command @Splat
}
```

#### "Oneliner"

```
function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock (
        [scriptblock]::Create(
            ('New-ADOrganizationalUnit {0} -Path "{1}" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0' -f $cn, $path)
        )
    )
}

# Or, using parentheses:

function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName (
        $server
    ) -Credential (
        $Credential
    ) -ScriptBlock (
        [scriptblock]::Create(
            ('New-ADOrganizationalUnit {0} -Path "{1}" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0' -f $cn, $path)
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really want to format it that way, try this:

```
function makeOU ($cn, $path)
{
  $sb = [scriptblock]::Create(
      "New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path (
        `"$path`"
       ) -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0"
    )

  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential `
    -ScriptBlock $sb
}
```

Comment: Your "if you really want to" makes it sound like I'm doing something grossly anti-idomatic to PS.  I'm perfectly willing to believe that so I wonder how you'd write it.

Comment: @ChrisNelson Sure, see my other answer.